# How do i declare and increment local variables in db2?

Tags: mysql, db2, ibm-cloud, local-variables, dashdb

I want to show row number for each of result set row, I have this query in mySQL

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 row, e.* FROM Employee e, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Here @rownum is local variable and would increment its value for each result row.
How do i write this query in db2 ( ibm's dashdb ) ?

Comment: Do you actually want a variable, or just to number the rows in a query?

Comment: i need a column which has row count like
`row  |s  name
1       |s   abc
2       |s  xyz`

Comment: Try: `select row_number() over() as row, e.* from Employee e`.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: perfect, it works, thank you

Comment: How do i create an variable like i've done in mysql?

Comment: @ian-bjorhovde, can you re-post your comment as an answer? 

Rahul, it sounds like you need to open a new question about creating the variable. If you ask a new question on a comment thread, there's a good chance it won't get answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to number the output rows, you can use the [`row_number()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html) function:

```
select 
    row_number() over() as row, 
    e.* 
from 
    Employee e
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to set a variable and set a value:

```
db2 -td@ "begin declare test integer; set test = 1; end @"
```

Or

```
begin
  declare test integer;
  set test = 1;
  set test = test + 1;
end @
```