# how to use local variables in db2 database?

Tags: variables, db2, ibm-cloud

I have this query in mySQL

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 row, m.* FROM Machine m, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Here @rownum is local variable and would increment its value for each result row.  How do I declare rownum in db2 ( ibm's dashdb ) ?

Comment: DB2 supports analytic functions (i.e. row number).  Why do you need to simulate row number in this way?

Comment: From [ExpertsExchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25611219/Local-Variables-in-DB2-SQL.html) `Most DB2 clients don't support local variables.  In fact, I don't know any that do.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i declare and increment local variables in db2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665529/how-do-i-declare-and-increment-local-variables-in-db2)

Comment: Are you planning to ask this question every week?

Comment: why is rownum a variable? -- it is just the value of `COUNT()` after the select statement -- is the whole point to get the count?  then use the count() function.

Comment: You can't have a question that is both db2 and mysql and then write the question using ms server syntax.  What platform are you actually using?

Comment: @mustaccio -- are you planning on answering this question every week?

Comment: @mustaccio no i'm not, somebody said to open a new thread to ask another question, so...

Comment: @Hogan well, it's just an example, i want a local variable in db2 query, how do i define and work on it?

Comment: @RahulKulkarni -- that still makes no sense -- what do you mean?  a query would never have a local variable -- a stored procedure might -- is that what you mean??

Comment: @Hogan https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch01s15.html  mysql can have variables in query, I want local variables like this in db2, is it possible? if so, how do I define and use them?

Answer (score 0):

DB2 supports window function `row_number`:

```
select
    m.*,
    row_number() over (order by <some_column(s)>)
from machine m;
```

Note that it needs an order by clause to produce a consistent row number list.

For more, see [this article](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-use-row_number-in-db2/)

Comment: @Tim - *How do I declare rownum in db2* - I think this is what OP asked

Comment: you don't need order by for the ROWNUMBER pseudo colunm https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052875.html

Comment: @Hogan - I know it's optional. I meant to say that if one wants to get a consistent row numbers assigned, then order by is required.